# Browser loses connection with Tomcat server

Tags: tomcat

I am sending a request to the tomcat server( version 7.0.32). While the server process the request, the browser loses the connection with server. I tried increasing the connectionTimeout value in server.xml to 80000 from 20000., but it still shows connection lost in browser after 5 minutes.

Do i need to make changes somewhere else or need to take care of anything else?

Comment: If you're doing something that takes so long that you're hitting browser timeouts, that's a pretty good signal that you should be doing it in a long-running background process / work queue instead.

Answer (score 2):

Well,

First, make sure that it is the connection from the browser to the server that is losing connection and not possibly the server losing connection to one of it's resources.  Having worked with Tomcat over and over again through the years, I know that sometimes it is difficult to determine the core issue of a problem from the error output in the Tomcat logs.

There are a few things to check in my experience.  For browser-server connectivity:

1. connectionTimeout
2. acceptCount
3. minSpareThreads

And then, if it's an issue with losing connectivity with a particular resource:

1. maxWait
2. maxActive
3. maxIdle
4. removeAbandonedTimeout

Hope that helps.  Let us know.